# $\gcd(a^2, b)$ such that $a$ is even and $b=2a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to grasp basic concepts of number theory, I would like to know if my reasoning is correct. When attempting to find the $\gcd(a, b)$ where $a  =  n^2$ and $b  =  2n$ such that $n$ is odd, I first express $n$ as an odd integer in terms of $k$, 
$$n = 2k + 1 : k \in \Bbb Z^+ $$
then I express $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n = 2k  + 1$
$$a = n^2 = (2k + 1)^2$$
$$b = 2n = 2(2k + 1)$$
and then I apply the Euclidean algorithm to find $\gcd\left((2k + 1)^2, 2(2k + 1)\right)$,
$$(2k + 1)^2 = (4k + 2)(k)  +  (2k + 1)$$
$$(4k + 2) = (2k + 1)(2) + 0$$
$$\therefore \quad \forall\; n = 2k + 1:k\in\Bbb Z^ + , \; \gcd(n^2,\, 2n)  =  n$$

---

Trying the other case when $n$ is even I express it as 
$$n = 2k:k\in\Bbb Z^ + $$
such that $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n = 2k$ gives
$$a  =  n^2  =  (2k)^2$$
$$b = 2n = 2(2k)$$
and apply the Euclidean Algorithm for $\gcd\left((2k)^2, 2(2k)\right)$
$$(2k)^2 = 2(2k)(k)  +  0$$
This result is a bit unclear to me since this is all new material, what does that result tell me about the $\gcd$ if the algorithm goes to zero in the first step?

From divisibility, I see this as $k\;|\;(2k)^2$ such that $\frac {(2k)^2}k = 2(2k)  =  2n$ from which I would claim that
$$\forall\; n = 2k : k\in \Bbb Z^ + , \;\gcd(n^2, 2n)  =  2n$$
Is this a correct reasoning about the relation between the divisibility, the Euclidean algorithm and the $\gcd$?

Comment: If it goes to zero in the first step, that means $\gcd(a,b)$ is $b$ and that therefore $b|a$.  A few things to keep in mind $\gcd(c*m,d*m) = m\gcd(c,d)$ and that $\gcd(n,kn) = n$ and $\gcd (a,b) = b \iff b|a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit simpler than that.

we know that if $a = n^2$ and $b = 2n$ that $n$ is a common divisor.

$a = n*n; b = 2*n$ so if there is any other common factor it will be a common factor of $2$ and $n$.

But as $n$ is odd there is no common divisor between $2$ and $n$ so the greatest common divisor is $n$.

This all hinges on understanding that

Lemma: $\gcd(c*m, d*m) = m\gcd(c,d)$

And therefore $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(n^2, 2n) = n\gcd(2,n) = n*1 = n$ (as $n$ is odd).

Comment: Which isn't to say what you did was wrong.  It looks good and correct.  Just a bit more complicated than necessary.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, from $Lemma : gcd((m)c, (m)d) = (m)gcd(c, d)$, if I let $gcd(c, d)=e$ and $m=\frac 1e$, it follows by definition that $gdc((m)c, (m)d)  = gcd(\frac ce, \frac de) = \frac 1e gcd(c, d) = \frac ee = 1$, correct?

Comment: I was assuming it was obvious from context that m was an integer.

Comment: It was and your explanation is very clear, my last question in the comments was out of context, which I should have mentioned. Sorry if this does not abide by the rules of the site. I was just wondering if I could apply the lemma to other things.

Comment: well, sure.  but not to fractions which wouldn't make gcd meaningful. But it's a pretty basic result.  Comes down to if $cm$ and $gm$ have factors in common either the will be a factor of $m$ or a common factor $c$ and $g$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  $gcd(a, b) =b$ in this case,  because as $n=2k$ then $b=4k|4k^2=a$.